# InfluxDB on Docker-Compose can't read SSL cert file

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, influxdb

I'm having some troubles trying to configure SSL with InfluxDB v1.8 running on Docker Compose.

I followed the [official documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/https_setup/#set-up-https-with-a-self-signed-certificate) to enable HTTPS with self-signed certificate, but the container crashes with the following error:

`run: open server: open service: open "/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt": no such file or directory`

It works if I run this configuration using `docker run` command:

```
docker run -p 8086:8086 -v $PWD/ssl:/etc/ssl \
  -e INFLUXDB_DB=db0 \
  -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin \
  -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword \
  -e INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_ENABLED=true \
  -e INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE="/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt" \
  -e INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_PRIVATE_KEY="/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.key" \
  -d influxdb
```

My docker-compose.yml is the following:

```
version: "3"
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    volumes:
      - influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
      - ./ssl:/etc/ssl/
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=db0
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_ENABLED=true
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE="/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt"
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_PRIVATE_KEY="/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.key"
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED=true

volumes:
  influxdb:
```

If I set `INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_ENABLED` to false, I can see that cert and key files are mounted as they should in `/etc/ssl` in the container ( `docker exec -it airq_influxdb_1 ls -la /etc/ssl` )

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variables passed in the `docker-compose.yml` are strings. You don't need to pass the quotes.
The influx DB is looking for the certificate under `"/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt"`...literally

Simply remove the quotes and the DB will start:

```
...
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_ENABLED=true
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE=/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt
      - INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_PRIVATE_KEY=/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.key
...
```