# Grafana/InfluxDB HTTPS with Docker Compose: Unable to Retrieve Certificate File

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, grafana, influxdb

I am pretty new to docker, and I have been trying to get the TIG Stack setup with docker compose. The stack was working perfectly before I tried to add the HTTPS stuff. I went through influxdb's and grafana's posts about HTTPS as well as some other threads on here to help, but I keep getting errors about the certs.

I am getting these current errors even though they are not directories but the actual cert/key files:

```
- influx: Error: read /etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt: is a directory 
- grafana: Error: ✗ *api.HTTPServer run error: read /var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.crt: is a directory
```

I have also gotten that the cert files are empty in the past, but that was before I added the volumes. I have checked and they are not empty.

The cert files are located at the following locations on ubuntu and they seem to have the correct information:

```
/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt
/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.key
/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.crt
/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.key
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Going through the docs, I created the certs and put them in the `/var/lib/grafana/ssl/` for grafana and `/etc/ssl/` directories on the machine (not part of docker I don't think - docker had not yet been spun up). Do I need to make them while the stack is running or something and then restart? I'm unsure how that would work. Or am I just not connecting the outside directories to docker correctly?

Below is my docker-compose.yml file. The lines I added for https that have broken it I have commented as having been added for https. All the other lines of code were there before and it worked fine. Yes, I know passwords and tokens are there - it's a demo file I'm modifying.

Here are the docs:

- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/set-up-https/
- https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.7/security/enable-tls/

Here are posts that I have read through and have sort of helped me:

- [InfluxDB on Docker-Compose can't read SSL cert file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63658200/influxdb-on-docker-compose-cant-read-ssl-cert-file).
- https://community.influxdata.com/t/https-tls-environment-variables-for-docker-for-influxdbv2/19539

```
version: "2"
services:
  influxdb:
    container_name: influxdb
    image: influxdb:latest
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "8086:8086"
    environment:
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=admin
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=password123
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=CBTNUGGETS-DEMO
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=CBTNUGGETS-DEMO-BUCKET
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=veryverysecuretoken
      - INFLUXD_TLS_CERT=/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt # added for https
      - INFLUXD_TLS_KEY=/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.key # added for https
    volumes:
      - ./vols/:/var/lib/influxdb2
      - ./ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt:/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt # added for https
      - ./ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.key:/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.key # added for https
    restart: always

  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - influxdb
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - /var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.crt:/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.crt  # added for https
      - /var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.key:/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.key  # added for https
    environment:
      - GF_SERVER_PROTOCOL=https # added for https
      - GF_SERVER_CERT_FILE=/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.crt # added for https
      - GF_SERVER_CERT_KEY=/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.key # added for https
      - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=marcusolsson-dynamictext-panel # works
    restart: always

  telegraf:
    container_name: telegraf
    image: telegraf:latest
    ports:
      - "57000:57000"
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_TOKEN=veryverysecuretoken
    links:
      - influxdb
    volumes:
      - ./conf/telegraf/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always

volumes:
  grafana_data:
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

I figured it out - I just needed to map the volumes to just the directories instead of the specific files:

```
version: "3"
services:
  influxdb:
    container_name: influxdb
    image: influxdb:latest
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "8086:8086"
    environment:
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=admin
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=password123
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=CBTNUGGETS-DEMO
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=CBTNUGGETS-DEMO-BUCKET
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=veryverysecuretoken
      - INFLUXD_TLS_CERT=/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.crt
      - INFLUXD_TLS_KEY=/etc/ssl/influxdb-selfsigned.key
    volumes:
      - ./vols/:/var/lib/influxdb2
      - /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
    restart: always

  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - influxdb
    volumes:
      - grafana_data/:/var/lib/grafana
      - /var/lib/grafana/ssl:/var/lib/grafana/ssl
    environment:
      - GF_SERVER_PROTOCOL=https
      - GF_SERVER_CERT_FILE=/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.crt # /etc/grafana/grafana.crt
      - GF_SERVER_CERT_KEY=/var/lib/grafana/ssl/grafana.key # /etc/grafana/grafana.key
      - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=marcusolsson-dynamictext-panel
    restart: always

  telegraf:
    container_name: telegraf
    image: telegraf:latest
    ports:
      - "57000:57000"
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_TOKEN=veryverysecuretoken
    links:
      - influxdb
    volumes:
      - ./conf/telegraf/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always

volumes:
  grafana_data:
```